# verilog/systemverilog passing parameters upwards through generated module hierarchy

Tags: parameters, verilog, system-verilog, hdl

Having a complex hierarchy of modules (many of them instantiated under generate) I need to get a bunch of wires from each of the low level modules 
 into an 1-dimensional array.

```
parameter HL_MODULE_PARAMETER = ll_module.LL_MODULE_PARAMETER
```

Seems to work just fine when *ll_module* is a plain instantiation. Not when *ll_module* is generated. 
Pre-calculating high level parameters top-bottom is out of the question since the hierarchy is very complex(not to mention the ugliness of the solution). There has to be a much elegant way to pass info about parameters upwards through hierarchy in this situation.

```
//-----------------------------------------------
module A #(
        parameter WIDTH = 8) (
                input x,
                output y,
                output[WIDTH-1:0] z);
endmodule // A
//-----------------------------------------------
module B #(
        parameter WIDTH = 10) (
                input x,
                output y,
                output[WIDTH-1:0] z);
endmodule // B
//-----------------------------------------------
module T #(
        parameter MOD_TYPE = 1,
        parameter WIDTH = MOD_TYPE ? g0.m.WIDTH : g1.m.WIDTH) (
                input x,
                output y,
                output[WIDTH-1:0] z);
generate
        if(MOD_TYPE == 1) begin : g0
                A m(.x(x), .y(y), .z(z));
        end else begin : g1
                B m(.x(x), .y(y), .z(z));
        end
endgenerate
endmodule
//-----------------------------------------------
```

The above code compiles with no errors. But simulation fails with message:

```
Error: Illegal reference to a parameter below a generate construct: g0.m.WIDTH
```

Comment: there is no way for doing it. You are asking the compiler to run in a loop by using parameters in lower levelhierarchies which are calculated after they are used. I was able to do it in `icarus` with violation of LRM but other tools either error out or do something else. you need to pre-calculate them.

Comment: I hope someone knows a workaround for this. In case of a complex design pre-calculating the parameters on the higher levels can be a coding nightmare...

Comment: you should probably re-thing your design in this case or use some extenal verilog generation scrtip. What you ask is outside of verilog ability.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `parameter HL_MODULE_PARAMETER = ll_module.LL_MODULE_PARAMETER` on multiple different tools on EDAPlayground and only one of them was happy with that syntax. All the others complained that the value on the right is not a constant expression. I think that according to the LRM module path expressions aren't considered to be constant expressions (even though they kind of are), so the error messages would conform to LRM. As a reference for this claim, have look in **A.8.3 Expression** at the `constant_expression` production and `module_path_expression`.

The tool you're using seems to be more permissive, in that it allows simple module path expressions, that don't go through generates, on the right hand side of a parameter assignment, but disallows the latter. I'm not sure you're going to have much luck finding a solution that satisfies your other conditions (avoid pre-calculating parameter values from top to bottom).